# Method for a position in a RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a scenario, where I need some help working with RecyclerView. The workflow is as follows:

- The user taps on a TextView in RecyclerView adapter and on click, i
  enable a button in Activity which was disabled earlier.
- On click on this enabled button, I want to change color of that particular position which was tapped.

Now what I have is an interface which provides the position on click of the TextView. What I really want to do is to have a function similar to this in my adapter:

```
public void changeColor(int position){
  //change background color of position
}
```

which then I can call from the activity `adapter.changeColor(position)`.

Can someone explain if this is possible or what can be the other ways to achieve this.

Comment: you can pass interface in adapter from your activity.

Comment: so what's the problem ? change the color of the background simply

Comment: @AbdulKawee it doesn't change the background of the selected position

Comment: @Rumit how do it do that.. doing it from activity is easy but from adapter..

Comment: @TheBat if you are using arrayList, you need to add boolean variable in class which defines set color or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can set these actions in `onBindViewHolder` method of your adapter

I will show `Kotlin` example of this, but in `Java` it will be pretty the same:

```
class ExampleAdapter(private var button: Button, private var arrayList: ArrayList<SimpleString>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val text = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)!!
        val layout = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.layout)!!
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ExampleAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentPosition = position
        viewHolder.text.text = arrayList[position].text

        viewHolder.text.setOnClickListener {
            button.isEnabled = true
            button.setOnClickListener {
                  viewHolder.layout.background = ... //set color here
                  notifyItemChanged(position)
            }
        }


    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): ExampleAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout, viewGroup, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrayList.size
    }

}
```

Comment: The button is not in adapter, it is in activity

Comment: button is in the activity ? so which position you will be selecting?

Comment: the position on which user tapped.. I get that position from an interface

Comment: @TheBat updated post, you can just pass Button declared in Activity to Adapter and then create onClickListener for a button each time you click on text view

Comment: That button is not with every cell.. the button is only one for the whole activity

Comment: @TheBat yes, thats why you have to declare, instantiate in Activity and pass that button to adapter

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are inflating data into RecyclerView using `ArrayList<ModelClass>`.

Set values for **enable|disable texview**, and it **color value** into model object.

- Implement textview Click in `onBindViewHolder()` method.
- Within `onClick()` method change model values for that particular position with new color value.
- Make sure that change is reflected with arraylist values and not just model object [can use arraylist.removeAt(pos) and then arraylist.add(pos,model)]
- At last call `notifyItemChanged(position)`.

Also I would recommend to use **tag** approach here